# can't compile my code when the header is added to another file

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a weird problem that I find hard to explain.

I have header file `outPut.h` and a source code file `outPut.cpp`. This compile easily on my code. However, if I add

```
#include "outPut.cpp"
```

to one of the header file in the *same code* I get an error about almost every line in `outPut.cpp`.

I now this is usually a problem with missing semicolor or something similar but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you show us the first ten lines of your outPut.cpp and outPut.h? Just add the code to the end of your question.

Comment: How are we supposed to find it? We can't see the contents...

Comment: I was hopping to find some clue similar to the answers I got. I don't want you to browse my code and my experience tells me that this sort of problems is in the mising-semicolon family.

Answer (score 4):

Don't include source (`.cpp`) files in header files, instead your source file should include the header and then you compile source file(s) directly (either explicitly passing to the compiler or with a makefile). Most likely you've introduced a circular dependency between the source and header file causing the many errors.

Comment: Please provide the smallest set of example code that exhibits the problem so we have a chance to see what may be wrong. Missing include guards are a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

you're probably missing [Include Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)